# error after "composer update"

Tags: magento2, error, composer

First time I installed a module via ssh, and I accidentally make "composer update".
Now my site has this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Tax db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3
Magento_Tax db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Tax db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3
Magento_Tax db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3
#0 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#2 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#5 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#8 {main}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this Commands :**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: done, but still error

Comment: run this command 
n98-magerun2 sys:setup:downgrade-versions after run above commands